# Windows 7 fonts Admin rights

Tags: windows-7, fonts, privileges

In Windows 7, is there a way to grant admin rights for installing fonts for non-admin users? Preferably without installing extra software.

I don't want to grant users full admin priveliges but it seems irritating that you can't let them run certain programs as admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to grant admin rights for installing fonts to non-admin users in Windows 7 by granting access to the appropriate file-system and registry locations.

This is described in detail in the following article:

http://www.bohack.com/2011/04/allowing-non-administrators-to-install-fonts-in-windows-7/

Comment: The suggestions given in the link is not working.. :( any help is appreciated??

Comment: Sorry @Yellow and Red that's as much as I know - the other option which I think is preferable is to offer escalation i.e. allow the user to do this with admin credentials

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 7 you can't grant admin rights for it.

But if you aren't admin, I can teach you how to get admin rights.

Just get a Windows LiveCD with "Password Recovery" function and change password of admin.
(You can get it free in many websites)

Comment: Obviously most people can't do this. There are plenty of ways to circumvent the admin password. I'm sure for the most part we're talking about a computer owned by someone else here.